# How can I have distinct folders for unit, integration and end-to-end tests in a Gradle/Spring Boot/Kotlin application?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-kafka, junit5

I have an application built with Spring Boot, Gradle and Kotlin which connects with Kafka and PostgreSQL. I'm using `resources/application.yml` as the config file.
I want to create a specific package for each of this kinds of tests: unit, integration and end-to-end, but now I have a package only for unit tests. What is the best way to do this? I'm using Junit5.

I want something like this:

```
application/
├─ src/
│  ├─ e2e/
│  ├─ integration/
│  ├─ main/
│  ├─ test/
build.gradle.kts
gradlew
gradlew.properties
settings.gradle.kts
```

Also, I want that when running unit tests my application don't connect to Kafka or Postgres, but when running integration tests I want it to do it. How can I do this?

I tried this configuration for Kafka, but didn't worked:

```yaml
spring
    autoconfigure:
        exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```

I also created a annotation to mock all Kafka consumer and producer (which worked, but I don't want to add this annotation in every test class )

```kotlin
@MockBeans(MockBean(MyConsumer::class), MockBean(MyProducer::class))
annotation class MockKafka

@SpringBootTest
@MockKafka
class MyAwesomeTest { // tests here }
```

My consumer looks like this:

```kotlin
@Component
class MyConsumer() {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    @RetryableTopic(
        attempts = "\${kafka-config.consumer.properties.retry.attempts}",
        backoff = Backoff(delayExpression = "\${kafka-config.consumer.properties.retry.delay}"),
        fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC
    )
    @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["\${spring.kafka.topic.my-topic}"],
        groupId = "\${spring.kafka.group-id}"
    )
    fun consumer(event: MyEvent) { // logic here }
}
```

My application.yaml file looks like this:

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
  application:
    name: nice_app
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nice_app
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          extra_physical_table_types: "PARTITIONED TABLE"
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    group-id: my-group
    topic:
      my-topic: my-topic

kafka-config:
  consumer:
    properties:
      retry:
        attempts: 5
        delay: 3000
```

```
Kotlin version: 1.5.0
Spring Boot version: 2.4.6
Gradlew version: 7.0.2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The folders and file patterns are controlled by Gradle. Please show your build file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Separating folders for different tests

Actually, Gradle did describe how to achieve this in the [official guide](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests). Here is an example `build.gradle.kts` for your case:

```gradle
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.0"

    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

group = "com.example.app"
version = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    create("intTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
    create("e2eTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}

val intTestImplementation: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

val e2eTestImplementation: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

configurations["intTestImplementation"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
configurations["e2eTestImplementation"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    intTestImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2"))
    intTestImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    intTestImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    e2eTestImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2"))
    e2eTestImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    e2eTestImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

val integrationTest = task<Test>("integrationTest") {
    description = "Runs integration tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["intTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["intTest"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

val end2endTest = task<Test>("end2endTest") {
    description = "Runs end-to-end tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["e2eTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["e2eTest"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("integrationTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("end2endTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.check {
    dependsOn(integrationTest)
    dependsOn(end2endTest)
}
```

Now the folder structure could be like this:

```
└── src
    ├── e2eTest
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   │   └── com/example/app/controller
    │   │       └── HelloControllerE2ETest.kt
    │   └── resources
    ├── intTest
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   │   └── com/example/app/controller
    │   │       └── HelloControllerIntTest.kt
    │   └── resources
    ├── main
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   │   └── com/example/app
    │   │       ├── controller/HelloController.kt
    │   │       └── App.kt
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── kotlin
        │   └── com/example/app/controller
        │       └── HelloControllerTest.kt
        └── resources
```

## Separating actions for different tests

I'm not familiar with Kafka, but in my own project I apply different Spring profiles to each test for different PostgreSQL settings.

First, assign profiles for each kind of tests in `build.gradle.kts`:

```gradle
...

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("integrationTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "integration")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("end2endTest") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "e2e")
}

...
```

Then, create profile-specific application config files to their corresponding `resources/config`:

```
└── src
    ├── e2eTest
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   └── resources/config
    │           └── application-e2e.yml
    ├── intTest
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   └── resources/config
    │           └── application-integration.yml
    ├── main
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   └── resources/config
    │           └── application.yml
    └── test
        ├── kotlin
        └── resources/config
                └── application-test.yml
```

The application will load the config in the following manner:

| Command | Profile | Config loading order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `./gradlew bootRun` | `default` | `applicaiton.yml` ( > `application-default.yml`) |
| `./gradlew test` | `test` | `applicaiton.yml` > `application-test.yml` |
| `./gradlew integrationTest` | `integration` | `applicaiton.yml` > `application-integration.yml` |
| `./gradlew end2endTest` | `e2e` | `applicaiton.yml` > `application-e2e.yml` |

Now you should be able to configure different behavior for each testing.

#### References

- https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config